# implementing following and followers doesn't work properly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a user model that has a slug field for lookup. I am trying to implement a user following and followers as its own model in my rest API, so I can save more info about the following and followers, and since I am trying to build a big project, I gathered it was a better practice.

The problem is that the code doesn't work and the user when he tries to follow does not follow the user.

I want to be able to follow the user if the user, and the user not able to follow himself and to follow once

models.py

```
class UserFollowing(models.Model):
    following = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="follows", null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    followers = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="followed_by", null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    followed_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserFollowingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    following_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    followers_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    user_is_following = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    followed_on = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserFollowing
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_followed_on(self, instance):
        return instance.followed_on.strftime("%d %B, %Y")

    def get_following_count(self, instance):
        return instance.following.count()

    def get_followers_count(self, instance):
        return instance.followers.count()

    def get_user_is_following(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        return instance.following.filter(slug=request.user.slug).exists()
```

views.py

```
class UserFollowAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = UserFollowingSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get("slug")
        UserFollowing.objects.delete(user_id=user, following_user_id=user)

    def post(self, request, pk):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get("slug")
        UserFollowing.objects.create(user_id=user, following_user_id=user)
```

urls.py

```
path("<slug:slug>/follow/", UserFollowAPIView.as_view(), name="users-follow"),
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**models.py**

```
class UserFollowing(models.Model):                            
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    following = models.ManyToMany(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="follows",null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    followers = models.ManyToMany(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="followed_by",null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    followed_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserFollowingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    following_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    followers_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    user_is_following = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    followed_on = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = UserFollowing
    fields = "__all__"

def get_followed_on(self, instance):
    return instance.followed_on.strftime("%d %B, %Y")

def get_following_count(self, instance):
    return instance.following.count()

def get_followers_count(self, instance):
    return instance.followers.count()

def get_user_is_following(self, instance):
    request = self.context.get("request")
    return instance.following.filter(slug=request.user.slug).exists()
```

**views.py**

```
class UserFollowAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = UserFollowingSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

def delete(self, request, pk):
    user = get_user_model().objects.get("slug")
    user.objects.delete(user_id=user, following_user_id=user)

def post(self, request, pk):
    user = UserFollowing.objects.get(user=request.user)  #this is the user that wants to follow someone
    who_to_follow = UserFollowing.objects.get('slug')  #i hope the slug is the user to be followed thoo ..user being followed
    user.followers.add(who_to_follow)
```

**urls.py**

```
path("<slug:slug>/follow/", UserFollowAPIView.as_view(), name="users-follow"),
```

i havent tested this code.....so its just intuition ....but it should work